# WCF - Get password from MessageHeader

Tags: wcf, security

I have a WCF service with security mode set to message. I use Username for client credentials type with a custom UserNamePasswordValidator.

```
 NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Message, false);
 binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
 binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

Can I retrieve the password on server side, after the user is authenticated?
Is the password saved in MessageHeader of the request? Can I get it from MessageHeader (after user is authenticated)?

Angela

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your question you have a WCF service which requires a user name and password for authentication. You have configured a custom [UserNamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx) for this purpose instead of relying on the default mechanism employed by WCF (= Windows).

Take a look here for more information on how to setup a custom username and pasword validator in WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx

I assume you have created a class that dervies from the UserNamePasswordValidator type. Your custom type is responsible for checking the username and password against a store (database, xml file...etc.) which contains a list of your users. The validator must determine if it is dealing with a valid user. If so, it can authenticate the user.

For example:

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        // Validator username and password here
        // bool isValid = ...;

        if (!isValid)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Access denied.");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see if you correctly implemented the custom UserNamePasswordValidator you already have a place where you can access the username and password which the client submitted.

If you want to access the username after the user has been authenticated, for instance in the body of one of service's methods you can use the following:

```
var userName = 
    OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

Take a look at the [ServiceSecurityContext type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx) for more information.

If you also want to make the password available, then I suggest you take a look at the following article:

http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx

I guess you could also extract the username and password from the current OperationContext as one of the comments of the previously mentioned article suggests.

```
public void MyServiceMethod()
{
    var context = OperationContext.Current;
    var token = context.IncomingMessageProperties.Security
                       .IncomingSupportingTokens[0].SecurityToken as  
                System.IdentityModel.Tokens.UserNameSecurityToken; 
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, that is correct I have my custom UserNamePasswordValidator, but I want to retrieve the password after the user is authenticated, say on service side when my service method is called.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented a solution based on the example from the above site. The question is if it exists a simpler solution. One of the comments mention using UserNameSecurityToken securityToken = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Security.IncomingSupportingTokens[0].SecurityToken as UserNameSecurityToken;

Comment: I'm sorry, but that was never the question. Your original question is how to retrieve the username and password when using a custom UserNamePasswordValidator. Not to find a simpler alternative to a possible solution which you never mentioned.

Comment: That "extract" doesn't work, at least not in all cases (not in mine).  There's only one token there, and it's not a UserNameSecurity one (went into the debugger to get true type).